# Problem in selecting a drop-down list with Selenium using Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Here is my example

```
<select name="ptype" class="form-control required" onchange="if(this.value==99){jQuery('#ptypeDescSpan').show();}else{jQuery('#ptypeDescSpan').hide();}" id="ptype">
  <option value="">---</option>
  <option value="1">op1</option>
  <option value="2">op2</option>
  <option value="3">op3</option>
  <option value="99">other</option>
</select>
<span id="ptypeDescSpan" style="display: none">
  <input type="text" name="ptypeDesc" text="true" class="" value="" id="ptypeDesc">
</span>
```

I want to select "other".
Here is my code.

```
elem1 = driver.find_element_by_id('ptype')
select1 = Select(elem)
select1.select_by_value('99')
```

After running the codes, I find out...
"No errors occured but nothing was selected"

First I checked the texts from each options, it showed correct results.

```
for i in select1.options:
    print(i.text)
```

Output was --- op1 op2 op3 other

I tried

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ptype > option:nth-child(5)').click()
```

But still, no errors occured but nothing was selected
Any suggestions?

Comment: Look for ActionChains workflows for select.  There are many simliar questions covering this.

Comment: @Hung-Yi Wu - I have added the solutions in the answer, did it work for you ?

Comment: @Akzy Thank you for the answer. I have tried these codes. No error messages were shown, but still... nothing changed. I was unable to select the option I want.

Comment: @Hung-YiWu - Are you getting any error ?

Comment: @Akzy I got no error running these codes, but nothing was selected.
By the way, I tried to open the drop-down list using driver.find_element_by_id('ptype').click(). It gave error message: Element is not clickable at point.  Any clue?

Comment: Try other locator , CSS or CLASS NAME, also can you share the URL

Comment: I also tried driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ptype"]/option[3]').click(). I got no error messages. But nothing was selected. 

The website contains information of the name, ID ... of the patients. I am not allowed to post the url. Instead, I will make a screen recording. Thank you!

Comment: I find out what's going on. There are 2 elements with "the same ID". The second element I want to find was hidden initially. It will be shown in a popout window after triggered. However, element locator found the first element with the same ID, and it becomes not clickable if there is a popup window. Therefore, it gives error message if I try to click. I solve the problem using "e1 = driver.find_elements_by_id('ptype')". e1[1] is the element I want. Problem solved!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below to select the value:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_id('id_of_select')
for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text == 'The Options I Am Looking For':
        option.click() # select() in earlier versions of webdriver
        break
```

***OR***

```
element= WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "Correct_ID_Element")))
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
actionChains.move_to_element(element).perform()
select = Select(element)
select.select_by_visible_text('other')
```

**Import**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

***OR you can enhance this like below***

```
element= WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "drop_down_ID")))
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
actionChains.move_to_element(element).perform()
select = Select(element)
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "xpath_of_locator")))
select.select_by_visible_text('other')
```